# Merge from Partition source

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

So I have the following code to create 2 tables. The first table is a staging table where I would perform a batch insert (NOLOGGING Sh-tuff left out). Second table is the live table.

```
CREATE TABLE STG_TBL(
  LIVE_TBL_ID NUMBER,
  CNT NUMBER,
  BATCH_ID NUMBER
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(BATCH_ID)
INTERVAL (1)
(PARTITION EMPTY VALUES LESS THAN (0));
/

CREATE TABLE LIVE_TBL
(
  LIVE_TABLE_ID NUMBER,
  CNT NUMBER
);
/
```

I insert some random but organized data into the staging table:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..100   -- Batch
  LOOP
    FOR j IN 1..10  -- Id
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO STG_TBL
      SELECT j, ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE*100,0) FROM DUAL, i;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I then try to perform a merge but the syntax shows it's incorrect... The select statement indicating the source table is valid but not in a merge. Other than using Execute Immediate Syntax any idea how to make it valid?

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..100 -- Batch
  LOOP
    MERGE INTO LIVE_TBL tgt
    USING(SELECT LIVE_TBL_ID, CNT FROM STG_TBL PARTITION FOR (i)) src
    ON (tgt.LIVE_TBL_ID = src.LIVE_TBL_ID)
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
    SET tgt.CNT = tgt.CNT + src.CNT
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (
      tgt.LIVE_TBL_ID,
      tgt.CNT
    ) VALUES (
      src.LIVE_TBL_ID,
      src.CNT
    );

    COMMIT;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION FOR (' || i || ')';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: The only way to explicitly refer to a partition like this would be to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate` or `dbms_sql`).  You almost never want to explicitly refer to a partition name, however.  You could put a `WHERE batch_id = i` predicate in your source and let Oracle automatically do the partition pruning.

Comment: Why do you have the staging table partitioned and the live table not? And why do you have it partitioned by batch id? Usually it's the other way around where the live, normally huge table is partitioned and the staging table is a non-partitioned one. Give the partitioning key I guess you use that as some sort of batch control table?

Comment: Thank you, Justin - is this for certain to happen? I was thinking about that but I wasn't sure Oracle would be smart enough to do it without a hint or something.

Comment: GVenzl, That's a great question! We insert into a partition table because we have very large batches. Dropping a partition will reduce fragmentation as a result reduce disk usage. We do partition the live table as well but for the question I didn't need to include that detail. But you are correct - we should partition the live table.

Comment: @OneClutteredMind - Assuming it can, yes, Oracle will prune the partitions.  That's one of the points of partitioning-- you don't have to care what partition a particular row is in.  If you had manually partitioned the table or if the partitioning predicate can't be pushed into a subquery where the table is referenced, you might not get partition pruning.  But on a simple query like this, if `WHERE batch_id = i` didn't cause partition pruning, it would be a rather serious bug.

Comment: @JustinCave, excellent! You should post the answer and get some credit for it. I appreciate your input. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @OneClutteredMind, that makes more sense to me now. And may I ask why you are using a `MERGE` statement. Is that to handle duplicates in the batch load itself or do you receive rows that have to be updated?

Comment: @gvenzl, In our situation we have a couple of tables where we merge. One table is an aggregate table. We keep track of counts for an item (that's what this example represents) and insert if it's the first time the item appears on our radar. We have another table where we update the data (not necessarily an aggregate but rather dates of that last time the item checked in) and insert if it doesn't exist. In this example we're keeping counts of an item. In this case, the item is represented by the "live_tbl_id".

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. It is unrelated to your immediate question but I think you still should be aware of the [Partition Exchange functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E08650B4-06B1-43F9-91B0-FBF685A3B848.htm#VLDBG1156) in Oracle. Rather than having to load the data and shovel it around again this feature allows you to load the data, prepare it (for example update the duplicates) and then just exchange the staging table with a partition of the live table. This is done regularly in big DWHs but it will require you to change your partitioning scheme and logic.

Comment: @gvenzl, would you be able to provide an example using Partition Exchange Functionality using my table structure? The link you provide points to Oracle Docs which is very dense. We really are looking for the quickest method without taking up a whole lot of disk space (table space, undo space, redo space, etc., etc.). Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to explain the entire concept of Partition Exchange in a single example but I have put one up on [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/dqlanrbbrc5rz4d5y18ukalrs) (let me know whether you can access it). Nevertheless, your partitioning scheme would most likely have to change as well as your duplicate detection process. There are several options for this and I recommend to have a look at the syntax in the [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#i2131250) for further explanation.

Comment: @gvenzl, thanks! You've opened a new path for me to explore.I really appreciate the help.